# How to use a value of cell as a SELECT param in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

1.**TextLang Table:**

```
| Key | En | Uk |
|'000'| 00 | 01 |
```

2.**Users Table**

```
| Id | Language |
|'11'| 'En'     |
```

I want to create a query that get the Value from Users Table and use it as a select param to get a value from TextLang Table.

**Example:**

```
SELECT Value(Users.Language) FROM TextLang 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id='11'
WHERE Key='000'
```

**Result:**

```
| En |
| 00 |
```

So I expect Value(Users.Language) to be equals to `'En'` And To get in this select the value `00`

How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear how your tables are linked, could you shed some light or perhaps show a little bit more of the structure?

Comment: @Kahn Got it right, Sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this TSQL will work, but it's not pretty. Something that's relatively fast to come up with though.

Either way, as far as I know, you're going to have to build some kind of dynamic SQL to be able to do what you're trying to do. :)

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX), @LAN_COLUMN VARCHAR(25)

SELECT @LAN_COLUMN = Language
FROM TextLang
JOIN Users ON Users.Id='11'
WHERE Key = '000'

SELECT @SQL = 
'Select '+@LAN_COLUMN+' FROM TextLang '
+' JOIN Users ON Users.Id=''11'''
+' WHERE Key = ''000'''

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Well tbh that's bad for a variety of reasons. First, you'd need to use more variables to store Users.Id and TextLang.Key values so you can use them dynamically on both parts of the script. Second, it's bad performance-wise as it has to basically fetch the data twice. But like I said, it's a first step and it gets the job done.